# keep-alive in ruby faraday

Tags: ruby, keep-alive, faraday

I have a method like this:

```
def make_request(path, params, body)
  raise ArgumentError.new('Endpoint not set!') if url.nil?
  conditions          = {url: url}
  conditions[:params] = params unless params.blank?
  connection          = Faraday::Connection.new(conditions)
  connection.run_request(:get, path, body, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
end
```

Then how can I add keep-alive there? Also, since I instantiate a connection object everytime I call this method(url might be different), does the keep-alive parameter still work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something [here](http://neo.com/2013/10/07/35x-increase-in-performance-with-one-line-change/) and [here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/314), but not tested it myself.

```
Faraday.new(uri) do |f|
  f.adapter :net_http_persistent
end
```

You can keep the connection creating a new method "connection"

```
def connection
  @connection ||= Faraday.new(@url_without_path) do |f|
                    f.adapter :net_http_persistent
                  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me in Faraday 1.4.1 with Ruby 3.0.1.  I  needed to install the gem "net-http-persistent"